# Sync workspace without re-download

Tags: version-control, perforce

We have uploaded a large project (large for our internet bandwidth) to depot.

Is it possible to give a exact copy of this project to our developers physically so they don't have to download the entire project from internet to sync their workspace with depot?

I tried `p4 sync -k` but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but after I set the client name equal to workspace name

```
p4 set P4CLIENT=MyWorkspace
```

and with

```
p4 flush
```

It worked. By the way according to perforce website `p4 sync -k` is alias to `p4 flush`.

Comment: "client" and "workspace" are synonymous -- you always need to set P4CLIENT to tell the server which client/workspace you're using.  I recommend using `p4 clean` after you've done a `flush` to verify that everything is correctly in sync, or it's possible to sneakily lose data on submit!

Comment: @Samwise thanks for clarifying that for me. now it makes sense why it worked